# Why does dplyr's coalesce(.) and fill(.) not work and still leave missing values?

Tags: r, dplyr, missing-data, fill, coalesce

I have a simple test dataset that has many repeating rows for participants. I want one row per participant that doesn't have NAs, unless the participant has NAs for the entire column. I tried grouping by participant name and then using `coalesce(.)` and `fill(.)`, but it still leaves missing values. Here's my test dataset:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

test_dataset <- tibble(name = rep(c("Justin", "Corey", "Sibley"), 4),
                       var1 = c(rep(c(NA), 10), 2, 3),
                       var2 = c(rep(c(NA), 9), 2, 4, 6),
                       var3 = c(10, 15, 7, rep(c(NA), 9)),
                       outcome = c(3, 9, 23, rep(c(NA), 9)),
                       tenure = rep(c(10, 15, 20), 4))
```

And here's what I get when I use `coalesce(.)` or `fill(., direction = "downup")`, which both produce the same result.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

test_dataset_coalesced <- test_dataset %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  coalesce(.) %>%
  slice_head(n=1) %>%
  ungroup()

test_dataset_filled <- test_dataset %>% 
  group_by(name) %>%
  fill(., .direction="downup") %>%
  slice_head(n=1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

And here's what I want--note, there is one NA because that participant only has NA for that column:

```
library(tibble)


correct <- tibble(name = c("Justin", "Corey", "Sibley"),
                  var1 = c(NA, 2, 3),
                  var2 = c(2, 4, 6),
                  var3 = c(10, 15, 7),
                  outcome = c(3, 9, 23),
                  tenure = c(10, 15, 20))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can `group_by` the `name` column, then `fill` the `NA` (you need to `fill` every column using `everything()`) with the non-NA values within the group, then only keep the `distinct` rows.

```
library(tidyverse)

test_dataset %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  fill(everything(), .direction = "downup") %>% 
  distinct()

# A tibble: 3 × 6
# Groups:   name [3]
  name    var1  var2  var3 outcome tenure
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Justin    NA     2    10       3     10
2 Corey      2     4    15       9     15
3 Sibley     3     6     7      23     20
```

Comment: This works, thank you! Out of curiosity, how is everything() different than . ?

Comment: @J.Sabree In your code, the dot `.` only tells the function where to put the output of the previous pipe (the `data` argument in your case), you're not actually telling the function which columns to `fill`, therefore you'll need to use `everything()`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
cleaned<- test_dataset |> 
  dplyr::group_by(name) |> 
  tidyr::fill(everything(),.direction = "downup") |> 
  unique()

# To filter out the ones with all NAs
cleaned[sum(is.na(cleaned[,-1]))<ncol(cleaned[,-1]),]

  name    var1  var2  var3 outcome tenure
  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Justin    NA     2    10       3     10
2 Corey      2     4    15       9     15
3 Sibley     3     6     7      23     20

``
```